# Submit ajax form on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that generates n ajax forms, one for each camera. On submit each loads a div with pictures from each camera. I'd like to submit the forms as they load.

So far I have this, taken from the action the form already takes when it submits, minus the on-click event binding the submit button to the ajax event.

Here's the HTML (Some CakePHP div soup removed)

```
<div id="CameraContainer">

    <form action="/Cameras/ajaxPicture" id="CameraShowForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Camera][camera]" label="Images:" value="CS011" id="CameraCamera" />
        <label for="datepicker_value">Date: </label><input name="data[Camera][date]" type="text" id="datepicker_value" value="12/13/2011 12:00:00" />
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Camera][count]" label="Images:" value="2" id="CameraCount" />
        <input id="submit-490507801" type="submit" value="Load Pictures" />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="ajaxPicture1" class="ajaxPicture"></div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({data:$(".CameraContainer").closest("form").serialize(),
        dataType:"html",
        success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#ajaxPicture1").html(data);},
        type:"post",
        url:"\/cameras\/ajaxPicture"
    });

        return false;});
```

These are both iterated for n camera containers, each has a unique ajax div and `CameraContainer` div for the form. Currently the `<script>` is inside the loop but it would be better if I could load it at the end of the page.

This is taken from code generated by my framework so I don't understand it completely; what I want it to (and though it would) do is to grab the nearest from to the element with the id `CameraContainer` (the form is inside this element), serialize this data and submit it to my ajax function, which is at `/cameras/ajaxPicture`. However the array it sends to that function is empty, thus the function returns no results.

How can I grab and submit the nearest Ajax form to a given element (and load it in a container div)?

Comment: Why would you want to submit a form post on page load?

Comment: Prepopulated forms that load pictures from each camera based on time, with a default time set. On page load you'll get several forms along with a couple pictures from each camera as examples. I could do it server side as well but I figured this made the most sense, and keeps the first image request working the same as all the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
$("#CameraContainer").find("form").serialize()
```

1. CameraContainer is an id so `#` and not a `.`
2. You don't search an element which is close to CameraContainer, you search an element which is in CameraContainer so use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function

Look at my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ72w/)